# Reference and proof of binomial tail identity

Tags: probability, combinatorics, reference-request, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

May I have a reference and/or proof of this identity? I saw it mentioned on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/392813/bounding-the-max-loaded-bin-usingm-choose-k-a-kk/393224#393224) and don't see how to show it.

For $p \in (0,1)$ and $0 \leq k < n$,

$$ \sum_{i=0}^k {n \choose i} p^i (1-p)^{n-i} = (1-p)^{n-k} \sum_{i=0}^k {n-k-1+i \choose i} p^i .$$

I've verified this numerically and tried some applying the binomial theorem to $(1-p)^{k-i}$ on the left, but that didn't seem to help, so I thought I'd ask for a reference.

**Update**: I have found a combinatorial proof and posted it as an answer below.

Comment: Can you be more specific in the ‘proof of interest’? If other people have the same problem, it would be easier to search for this question with this information added

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After multiplication with $(1-p)^{k-n}$ we want to show for $p \in (0,1)$ and $0 \leq k < n$
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{n}{i}p^i(1-p)^{k-i}=\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{n-k-1+i}{i}p^i}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

Both sides of (1) are polynomials in $p$ of degree $k$. We show equality by comparing coefficients of equal powers of $p$. We use the *coefficient of* operator $[p^t]$ to denote the coefficient of $p^t$ of a series.

> We start with the right-hand side of (1) and obtain for $0\leq t \leq k<n$:
> \begin{align*}
> [p^t]\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{n-k-1+i}{i}p^i=\color{blue}{\binom{n-k-1+t}{t}}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

This was the easy part. Now the left-hand side of (1):

> \begin{align*}
> [p^t]&\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{n}{i}p^i(1-p)^{k-i}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^t\binom{n}{i}[p^{t-i}](1-p)^{k-i}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^t\binom{n}{i}\binom{k-i}{t-i}(-1)^{t-i}\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^t\binom{n}{i}\binom{-k+t-1}{t-i}\tag{4}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\binom{n-k+t-1}{t}}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}
> in accordance with (2) and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we apply the rule $[p^{k-j}]A(p)=[p^k]p^jA(p)$. We also set the upper limit of the sum to $t$ since other indices do not contribute to the sum.
- In (3) we select the coefficient of $p^{t-i}$.
- In (4) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-n}{k}=\binom{n+k-1}{k}(-1)^k$.
- In (5) we apply the *[Chu-Vandermonde identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity#Chu%E2%80%93Vandermonde_identity)*.

Comment: Very nice, thank you! You may enjoy the alternate proof that I found, which I will post next as a separate answer.

Answer (score 3):

I found a combinatorial argument as well.

We want to show $\Pr[\text{Binom}(n,p) \leq k] = (1-p)^{n-k} \sum_{i=0}^k {n-k-1+i \choose i} p^i$.

Imagine a process where we flip coins with bias $p$ until we have seen $n-k$ tails, then stop. The chance that we stop at or before step $n$ is equal to $\Pr[\text{Binom}(n,p) \leq k]$, i.e. the chance that $n$ flips contain at least $n-k$ tails.

Now we calculate the probability a different way.

The number of ways that we can stop at step $t$, for $t \geq n-k$, is the number of ways to have $n-k-1$ tails in the first $t-1$ flips. Of course the $t$th flip must be a tails, since we stop. So the number of ways is ${t-1 \choose n-k-1} = {t-1 \choose t-n+k}$. The probability of each of these ways is $(1-p)^{n-k} p^{t-n+k}$. So the total probability of stopping at or before step $n$ is
\begin{align}
  &\sum_{t=n-k}^n {t-1 \choose t-n+k} (1-p)^{n-k} p^{t-n+k} \\
  =& \sum_{i=0}^k {n-k-1+i \choose i} (1-p)^{n-k} p^i
\end{align}
after reparameterizing by defining $i=t-n+k$, i.e. replacing each $t$ with $i+n-k$.

Comment: Very nice approach. (+1)